# Using regex to check if a string has at least two numbers

Tags: java, regex

After digging around on stack overflow, I found some code which checks if the string is alphanumeric and longer that 8 chars. It works great. Now how do I make it return true if it contains at least 2 numbers? I think I have to add `\d{2}` somewhere.

```
String pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";

if (s.matches(pattern) && s.length() >= 8){
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a separate if condition. A single regex will do all for you.

```
String pattern = "^(?=.*?\\d.*\\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$";
```

Comment: You're welcome.. or `"^(?=.*?\\d.*\\d)(?=.*?[A-Za-z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$"`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in one line:

```
return s.matches("(?=(.*?\\d){2})[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}");
```

Answer (score 2):

Assert with a positive lookahead:

```
^(?=(?:\D*\d){2})[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/qM1sK5/1).

Comment: Thanks! if I knew about regex earlier, my life would have been much easier. I used to convert characters to their ASCII values and comparing.

Comment: @Jack You parsed the strings yourself, I see :P

Comment: Yeah, coming from Python, it's nice to see features like this once in a while